# gzinflate: max. space to avoid out-of-memory?

Tags: php, gzip, out-of-memory

When decompressing with `gzinflate`, I found that - under certain
circumstances - the following code results in out-of-memory errors. Tested with PHP 5.3.20 on an 32bit Linux ([Amazon Linux AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) on [EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_ec2)).

```
$memoryLimit = Misc::bytesFromShorthand(ini_get('memory_limit')); // 256MB
$memoryUsage = memory_get_usage(); // 2MB in actual test case
$remaining = $memoryLimit - $memoryUsage;
$factor = 0.9;
$maxUncompressedSize = max(1, floor($factor * $remaining) - 1000);
$uncompressedData = gzinflate($compressedData, $maxUncompressedSize);
```

Although, I calculated the size of `$maxUncompressedSize` conservatively, hoping to give `gzinflate` sufficient memory, I still get:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 266143484 bytes) in foo.php on line 123

When changing the value of `$factor` from `0.9` to `0.4`, then the error goes away, in this case. In other cases `0.9` is OK.

I wonder:

**Is the reason for the error really that `gzinflate` needs more than double the space of uncompressed data? Is there possibly some other reason? Is `$remaining` really the remaining memory at disposal to the application?**

Comment: What are you `gzinflate()` ing in the first place that is so big?

Comment: `gzinflate` probably allocate memory to the ouput, temporary blocks of data. You should read it's implementation.

Comment: PHP is not C, you can't realistically expect `gzinflate` and PHP to need no more than the size of the uncompressed string (even if you leave margin). Plus, PHP is rather loose when it comes to memory, this is likely normal behaviour.

Comment: @Pekka I deflate responses from APIs, some of them indeed being extremely big. Unfortunately that is outside of my control. Anyhow, the size of uncompressed data doesn't really matter: As I explained, adjusting the value of `$factor` from `0.9` to `0.4` solves the issue. So, the problem is not the size of the uncompressed data, but the size of memory that `gzinflate` (temporarily) allocates when working.

Comment: It would be somewhat helpful if someone could confirm that the value `$remaining` really is the *remaining memory at disposal to the application*, or not.

Comment: @feklee it is, the issue there is not a miscalculation of the remaining memory but `gzinflate` using more memory than you expected.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but might moving out to the command line be an option? The memory limit doesn't apply there.

Comment: @Pekka웃 As a last resort, yes. But that may open other issues.

Comment: @Mahn: The question is how to safely calculate the maximum uncompressed size. Strangely, a factor of 0.9 often works. Only in the particular test case, I needed to lower it to 0.4. This does not make me trust the calculation at all anymore.

Comment: Your code does not show where $compressedData is filled with data. You fill it before memory_get_usage(), right ?

Comment: @Jean: Yes, it's filled before any of the above code gets called.

Comment: The doc for gzinflate states: The function will return an error if the uncompressed data is more than the optional parameter length. So if it does work for a factor of 0.4, it should work for a factor of 0.9 without needing more memory, since 0.4 was already enough… Could the error be coming from somewhere else ? Also, why don't you use memory_get_usage(true); ?

Comment: @Jean `memory_get_usage(true)` sounds like a good idea. Concerning `$factor` and the second parameter to `gzinflate`: Possibly `gzinflate` uses the value of that parameter internally to allocate the output buffer. If that is the case, then a larger value for `$factor` would lead to temporarily higher memory demand.

Comment: It is indeed possible. IMHO, the issue lies with `memory_get_usage(true)`. Using true should give a higher memory usage value, because should take everything into account.

Comment: @Jean Please turn your comment into an answer: I finally got around to trying out `memory_get_usage(true)`, and now I could set `$factor = 1` without getting an error message.

Comment: @feklee Thanks for coming back to tell me. I just turn it into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible. IMHO, the issue lies with `memory_get_usage(true)`.

Using `true` should give a higher memory usage value, because should take everything into account.